# Not able to run AWS CLI commands through windows script(.bat file)

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, batch-file, aws-cli

I am trying to create a "aws_configure.bat" file which will run aws commands. I need to configure "aws_configure.bat" file as windows task. I created my script with below content.

```
aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID <mykey>
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <myskey>
aws configure set region us-west-2
aws dynamodb list-tables
```

When I am trying to run this script then its printing the first line in cmd window. Can someone please suggest what is the problem here. Why my script is not able to run the aws cli commands. (I have installed aws cli in my system and when i am running these commands directly in cmd window, everything is working fine).

Comment: Your first line should be: `aws configure set aws_access_key_id <mykey>`. Refer the amazon documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html

Comment: Yes.. My first line is same in my file. I tried with both upper and lower cases for aws_access_key_id but still the same problem..

Comment: You can work without creating the credentials or config file by exporting the credentials before running the CLI commands. If you want the credentials to be available for the whole session, export them as environment variables. Refer AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html. If you want the credentials to be available only for 1 command, you can do: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<mykey> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<mykey> aws dynamodb list-tables --region us-west-2`

Answer (score 2):

You should consider creating and configuring your AWS credentials *outside* of your batch file, then referencing the [named profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html) from the batch file.

Run `aws configure --profile myprofile`, and provide the information required.

Then from your batch file, call `aws dynamodb list-tables --profile myprofile`.

To setup the prefered/default profile, set `AWS_PROFILE=myprofile` in system environment.  With this method, you will not need to reference the profile in the batch file.

Comment: Is there any way to creating and configuring my AWS credentials in same batch file ??